# what happen for previous client request if tomcat is restarted by out of memory

Tags: tomcat

suppose, there are two tomcat servers and one of tomcat server is stopped and started again.
At that time one client was requesting order list from the tomcat server.

In this situation, how the request will be processed?

1. the request will be cancelled. so client shoudl request again.
2. the request hand over to another tomcat server and the tomcat server will continue client's request

thanks for reading.

Comment: It depends on how they are configured, *nu?*

Comment: if there is session clustering for tomcat servers, what would be happened? would be the second server will handle the request continually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general the following are more widely used mechanism for Tomcat deployment in HA mode (without reverse proxy)

1. Tomcat clustered with load balancer and sticky session
2. Tomcat native clustering is used (requires multi-cast enabled network)
3. External session store/manager is used

In the above context:

> the request will be cancelled. so client shoudl request again.

In any of the above cases, the client will have to reissue the request

> the request hand over to another tomcat server and the tomcat server will continue client's request

This cannot happen as the socket between server/client will be closed

> if there is session clustering for tomcat servers, what would be happened? would be the second server will handle the request continually?

The second server will handle any new requests, the client will not need to re-login. The original request will be terminated any way

There is a case, if there is intelligent load balancer, when the 1st Tomcat goes down and the load balancer determines this before the request is dispatched or ***[this is more theoretical, I have not come across any load-balancer practically that does this] during the course of it receiving response from the 1st Tomcat***, it can dispatch to the 2nd Tomcat

Comment: Thank you very much sir!, this is what I exactly want to know. _()_